# How to use bcp in on a table with an indexed view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm using SQL Server 2017 and want to use "bcp in" in a script to populate tables in several databases.  I am unable to import data into a table that has an indexed view. The following is an MCVE that reproduces my problem:

1. Run the script at the end of this post to populate a test database with two tables, an indexed view and some data.
2. Run **bcp out** to export the test data from the table Table1 to a file:

```
bcp [dbo].[Table1] out .\Table1.bcp -S "localhost" -d TestDB -T -k -N
```

3. Delete the test data from Table1:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table1]
```

4. Attempt to import data into Table1 using **bcp in**:

```
bcp [dbo].[Table1] in .\Table1.bcp -S "localhost" -d TestDB -T -k -N
```

Result: fails with an error message `INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'...`

*Note: if I drop the index [ix_v1] on the view, this will succeed: the problem only occurs if the table is referenced by an **indexed** view.*

4. Attempt to import data into Table1 using **bcp in** with the -q switch:

```
bcp [dbo].[Table1] in .\Table1.bcp -S "localhost" -d TestDB -T -k -N -q
```

Result: fails with an error message `Invalid object name '[dbo].[Table1]'`

5. Attempt to import data into Table1 by specifying the table name without [] delimiters, and with the -q switch:

```
bcp dbo.Table1 in .\Table1.bcp -S ".\SqlExpress17" -d TestDB2 -T -k -N -q
```

Result: the data is successfully imported.  However this does not meet my requirements, because I want a generic script that will also work with table names that require delimiters (e.g. `[dbo].[My Table]`).

Question: Is there a way to use bcp to import data into a table with an indexed view, while specifying a delimited, schema-qualified table name on the bcp command line?

**Script to populate an empty database TestDB**

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Table1Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Table1Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Table1Id] ASC)
 )
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [Table2Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Table2Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Table1Id] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [Table2Id] ASC)
)
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v1] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT 
    T1.Table1Id, T1.Table1Name,
    T2.Table2Id, T2.Table2Name
    FROM [dbo].[Table1] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table2] T2
    ON T1.Table1Id = T2.Table1Id
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_v1] ON [dbo].[v1] (Table1Name, Table2Name)
GO
INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES 
 (1, 'One')
,(2,'Two')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for the bcp [`-q` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) states:

> Enclose the entire three-part table or view name in quotation marks
> ("")

Instead of enclosing the individual object name parts in square brackets, enclose the ***entire qualified object name argument*** in double-quotes. 2-part names are allowed here since you specified the `-d` option for the database context:

```
bcp "dbo.Table1" in .\Table1.bcp -S ".\SqlExpress17" -d TestDB2 -T -k -N -q
```

This will allow object names that don't conform to regular identifier naming rules. The `-q` option will additionally `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` to allow inserting into a tables with indexed views, filtered indexes, etc.

However, you'll still get an error if the table name contains a period. An undocumented work-around is to enclose both the schema and object name in double-quotes:

```
bcp "dbo"."Table.NameWithDot" in .\Table1.bcp -S ".\SqlExpress17" -d TestDB2 -T -k -N -q
```

Comment: That works, thanks.  Seems a bit bizarre that quoted identifiers should be required in this specific case - would you agree that this appears to be a bug in the bcp.exe utility?

Comment: @Joe, this isn't a bug. The example I provided worked but is contrary to the documentation. I corrected my answer. Please review.

Comment: The recommendation to enclose the entire qualified object name in quotes doesn't work in the (admittedly pathological) case of schema and/or table names that contain a period character.  So I've gone for your original solution of quoting schema name and table name separately.  Whether it's a bug or a feature is subjective, but when something apparently unrelated like adding an indexed view breaks existing import scripts, I'd lean towards calling it a bug.

Comment: @joe, I didn't try the period character. One could make the argument it's a design shortcoming rather than a bug but the end result is the same.

Comment: I think your first answer is superior to the second one, as it will still work if you rename [Table1] above to use a period [Table.1].   `bcp "dbo"."Table.1" in ...` will work in this case, whereas `bcp "dbo.Table.1" will give an error "The -d database name option is not supported when a 3 part dbtable name is specified.".   Would you consider rolling back your edit to the original, working answer.

Comment: @Joe, I added the undocumented method to my answer.